# Big height image in small height div Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have an image with dimensions of height: 751 and width of 244 px and I need to put this image to div with dimensions of 132x132 and I want this picture to have background-size: contain and not to be stretched. I have tried with img-fluid, but nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

```css
.thumbs-container {
  width: 132px;
  height: 132px;
}

.item1 {
  background-size:contain;
 }
```

```html
<div class="thumbs-container col-2">
          <img
            class="item1 img-thumbnail"
            src="http://via.placeholder.com/244x751"
          />
        </div>
```

Comment: Please show the code that demonstrates what you've tried

Comment: use object-fit with a polyfill for ie

Comment: `background-size:contain;` not working on on `img` tag try to use `object-fit:  contain` instead

Comment: @Zim I added code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.thumbs-container {
  width: 132px;
  height: 132px;
}

.item1 {
  background: url('http://via.placeholder.com/244x751')no-repeat center center;
  width: 132px;
  height: 132px;
  background-size:cover;
 }
```

```html
<div class="thumbs-container col-2">
          
          <div class="item1"></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: use background image instead of img tag and set `background-size:cover`

Answer (score 0):

Set height of **.item1** to 100%

```css
.item1 {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`background-size:contain` only works for images set as background in css.
Just remove the `img` tag and set your background in css instead like this:

`HTML`

```
<div class="thumbs-container col-2"></div>
```

`CSS`

```
.thumbs-container {
    width: 132px;
    height: 132px;
    background: url('http://via.placeholder.com/244x751') no-repeat center/contain;
}
```